# Mathematical proof for approximated equation basing on sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given $n$ sets i.e., $A_1, A_2,\dots, A_n$ where $|A_i|$ is the number of elements in the set $A_i$, let $U=A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_n$.
Can anyone prove that for sequences $|B_1|\ge|B_2|\ge\dots\ge|B_m|$ selected from the $A_i$ (so each $B_j=A_i$ for some $i$),

$$|B_1| + |B_2| +\dots+ |B_m|\approx\left(\frac{|B_1\cup B_2\cup\dots\cup B_m|}{|U|} + \frac{|(B_1\cup B_2\cup\dots\cup B_{m-1})\cap B_m|}{ 2|B_m|}\right)|U|.$$

This equation is holding good on a very huge data and proved to be be correctly approximating the closest value. But mathematical proof is needed to substantiate it. Can any one prove it mathematically?

Comment: This was a fairly complicated TeXification, double check the formulas to make sure I did it right.

Comment: I think the equation needs some cleanup before it can even be analyzed for correctness. Several undeclared indexes ($i,j,k,m$) show up in the equation; what are these referring to? In the first paragraph it seems that there are $n$ sets but this apparently changes to $m$ in the equation and second paragraph.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The indices $i,j,k,m$ are supposed to represent the relative order of $n(A_1),\ldots,n(A_m)$. It would have been much simpler to just assume that $n(A_1) \geq \dots \geq n(A_m)$. Also, perhaps more than two terms were intended in the sum, though granted only two appeared.

Comment: Please see the following example for better understanding. Lets take 6 sets. so n=6 i.e., A={1,2,3,4}, B={1,5,6,7,8,9,10}, C={1,2,3,4,10} D={4,5,6,7,10}, E={2,3,8,9} and F={3,8,9} then Universal set, U= Union(A,B,C,D,E,F)={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} thus |U|=10. Now say m=2 where I am considering B and C. then n(B) + n(C) ≈ [n(B ∪ C)/|U| +n((B) ∩C) /2n(C) ] * |U| That is 7+5 ≈ [10/10 + 2/(2*5)]* 10 that implies 12 ≈ (1+0.2)*10 that implies 12 ≈1.2 *10 that implies 12≈12.0  where n(B) = 7, n(C)= 5, n(B ∪ C)= 10, n((B) ∩C)= 2

Comment: It is okay to prove that the approximation deviates by a constant 'k' in cases. Say for example m=3 and say considering D,E,F from the above mentioned example. then n(D) +n(E) +n(F)  ≈ [n(D ∪ E∪ F)/|U| +n(((D ∪ E) ∩F) /2n(F) ] * |U| that is 5+4+3 ≈ [9/10 + 3/(2*3)] * 10 that is 12  ≈ 1.4*10 that is 12  ≈14.0 .Here the deviation of approximation k= 14-12= 2.

Comment: @radha I updated the question based on my interpretation of your examples. Feel free to revert or edit if you think I misinterpreted your intent.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro thanks for the edit. It is absolutely the right and easy way of representation.

Comment: There is still some work left on making the error bound precise before one can prove or refute it. You say that the error can be at most a constant $k$, but what is $k$ allowed to depend on? If it is just dependent on $n$, or on $|U|$, then it's false. Are the $B_i$ allowed to be repeated (i.e. $B_1=B_2=\dots=A_i$ for some $i$)? If so then it's false because then if all are the same the left side can get arbitrarily large while the right side is fixed.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Bi's cannot be repeated.  In our application of this equation on the data we are considering, we can always carry it forward by putting some value for 'k' just that we wont consider the combinations of 'm' sets where the deviation( strictly considering RHS-LHS but not the mod value) cannot be negative. We can always ignore those failing combinations of m sets whose deviation 'k' is negative(RHS part minus LHS part ).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The proof can proceed showing maximum or minimum deviation possible irrespective of any precise bound. Since we always have the option putting some 'k' value and proceed further in our application data set. Basing on the requirement the deviation value can change.

Comment: Proof can proceed without any precise bound on the deviation measure. As the deviation measure is just like a threshold which varies from domain to domain which depends on the requirement of application for what we are using it. The proof can proceed by justifying an upper and lower bound on the deviation measure 'k' which is given as the difference between RHS and LHS part of the mentioned formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $A_m$ is disjoint from all other sets. Then your formula reads
$$ n(A_1) + \cdots + n(A_m) = n(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_m). $$
This is not true. For example, suppose that $n(A_m) = 1$ and $A_1=\cdots=A_{m-1}$,  $n(A_1) = N$. The left-hand side is $N(m-1)+1$, while the right-hand side is $N+1$.

Comment: Note that the original equation had an $\approx$, so perhaps it is not meant to be exactly true in all cases (not sure about what is meant, though...)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Under what notion of approximation is $100m$ the same as $100$?

Comment: In most of the cases, the approximation is close enough. The deviation of some constant 'k' is okay as we are trying to closely approximate but no need to show it is exact. If it deviates, the deviation can be set as athreshold saying the value can be that closely approximated with a deviation of 'k'. Please see the example given in the above comment for better understanding.